# How to create a color patterns in Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

I am working on Android Canvas. I am trying to set this kind of zigzag color in my rectangle how can I achieve this.

[image]

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
c.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, myPaint);
```

Comment: downvoter please post the reason

Comment: Well you need to alternate in steps between red and black. So you could say `zigzagHeight = height / numberOfZigzags` and then for every value of `zigzagHeight` you would draw a rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example, you can use `BitmapShader`:

```
init() {
Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourseidofthebmpfile);
    BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP, 
        Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
}
    onDraw(...) {
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}
```

Comment: how to set colors in shader red and balck?

Comment: in this case you have to prepare for bitmap file. or generate this bitmap inside of the code.

Comment: what is patternBMP in it?

Comment: @AndroidGeek ,this is raster bitmap data.

Comment: I did not understand that one :/ i have to check it

Comment: @AndroidGeek, this is faster and more useful for complicated backgrounds than complicated setColor-drawRect case (in the other answer).

Comment: it is but i haven't worked on it before I am under process

Comment: can you tell me how to use setColor and setShader together??
I want to apply setColor over my shader

Comment: You cannot blend setColor and setShader. But there is another method, I've not used already : `ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 0);
p.setColorFilter(filter);`

Comment: thanks @Vyacheslav you helped me a lot in this thanks so much :)

Comment: How can I contact you personally?

Comment: write to me into chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101083/discussion-between-vyacheslav-and-android-geek).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the help of `Bitmapshader` easily:

- **Firstly** take a image like this [image]
- Put this image in drawable and name it `stripes`.
- Now Apply **BitmapShader** like this on your canvas:

  ```
  BitmapShader shader;
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stripes);
  shader  = new BitmapShader(bm, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
  paint.setShader(shader);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw four rectangles one by one.

```
public void init(){
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        canvas.drawRect(100, 100 * i, 200, 100 * (i + 1), mPaint);
    }
}
```

Screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: I liked your logic but i have too many dynamic lines i have to set it on selected lines only. It is really good i appreciate thanks a lot for your efforts..I will definitely save it for future use :)